# Cancelling requestAnimationFrame after set amount of time

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function animate() {
// call other function

offset += 3;
if (offset > 15) offset = 0;

/// make the animation loop loop
var request = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

And then in my HTML:

```
<body onload="animate()" >
```

This all works fine, and it keeps the animation continuously looping, which is great. But I want to figure out how to make this animation run for say 4 seconds and then stop.

The "call other function" is just a line that moves down and then resets itself to give the impression of moving down a stretch of road. It is all done in Canvas at the moment.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame`'s argument which is elapsed time in milliseconds - this will give you a very accurate time:

```
function loop(elapsedTime) {

    if (elapsedTime >= 4000) return; /// break loop after 4 seconds

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);    /// provides elapsed time as arg. to loop
}

/// start loop with rAF to get a valid argument first time:
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

## [Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/rZva8/)

From the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame):

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a
>   DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the time, in milliseconds but
>   with a minimal precision of 10 µs, at which the repaint is scheduled
>   to occur.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for 4000ms elapsed time like this:

```
var start = Date.now();

function animate() {

    if(Date.now()-start>4000){return;}

    requestAnimFrame(loop);

    // do stuff

};
```

This way you exit before calling the next loop with RAF (so no need to cancel).

Comment: `Date.now()` or `new Date()` rather than `new Date.now()`, though. (And a semicolon isn’t necessary at the end of a function declaration.)